# C# client : how to get current datetime from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, data-binding, dispatchertimer

I have used a **date time** in my project. My project is **client server** and developed with **c#**.

Now, I want to **get date time clients** from **SQL Server on server**, that when the system date time client was in trouble, Application get **current date** time from **server**.

For example: A **timer** that each hour to run the **SQL server** following command:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**Edit:** C# application get date time from SQL Server and each hour once, your update date time

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME();
```

Check docs for more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188383(v=sql.110).aspx

Although it would be simpler to just use DATETIME.NOW in C# instead of selecting this value from the database, but it depend on your setup.

Comment: sorry, I do not know how this code (SELECT SYSDATETIME()) was used in c#

Answer (score 0):

You must

- open a connection to sql server
- execute a select command using that connection
- get the proper value from the returned data

C#

```
qlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT GETDATE() as CurrentTime";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
```

Comment: Is this code that right: var ts = dc.SystemSettings.Select(c => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.CurrentTimestamp().Value).First();

Comment: ExecuteScalar would be better here.  @MohammadRezaHasanzadeh - the answer should work.

Comment: True, ExecuteScalar returns a single value, is it better. You can do 
sqldate = (DateTime= cmd.ExecuteScalar();